# How to find an html tag without an id or class name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am able to access the contents of an html tag when it has an id associated with it, but cannot find html tags without ids.

I am able to access the content I need when an id exists:

```
<div id="anything"> 
  <div class="anything">
  What I need
  </div>
</div>
```

But if the tag looks like this:

```
<div id="anything">
  <div>
    <div class="something">
      What I need 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find it using .findAll, .find_next_sibling, or .children
I tried tfinding it the following way:

```
x = soup.find('div', attrs ={'id':'anything'}) 
type(x.div) 
print(x.div.text)
```

But type(x.div) returns NoneType....???

```
for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'anything'}):
    bar = foo.find('div', attrs={'class': 'anything'})
    print(bar.contents[0].text)
```

This prints "What I need" in the first html block, but not the second

This works on tags with an ID, but I cannot find a way to make it work to find div without ID

Comment: Just get rid of the `attrs` parameter and it will find all the DIVs.

Comment: If there are many divs (~100), then how do I find the one I am looking for (DIV without id or class) after I find_all DIVs?

Comment: What is the criteria for the one you're looking for?

Comment: In my html example above, the text I need is within a <div class="something"> tag, but that tag is within a <div> tag that has no id or class. I cannot parse from <div id="anything"> to <div> and finally to <div class="something> to get What I need.

Comment: Looks like it's just a typo. The second call should be `{'class': 'something'}`, not `{'class': 'anything'}`

Comment: @conorjg could you please be more specific? - perhaps you have a typo, or there's some corner case you're trying to avoid, but it doesn't come through in your example, a tweak to your code seems to work for both cases:
`for foo in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'anything'}):
    bar = foo.find('div')
    print(bar.text.strip())
`
what are you trying to solve for specifically?

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate down the div chain like this:

```
print(soup.div.div.text)
```

output:

```
  What I need
```

Comment: This is only a subsection of the entire html, so I cannot just keep attaching .div. I tried to save this value: x = soup.find('div', attrs ={'id':'anything'}) and then use print(x.div.text), but type(x.div) = NoneType

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if I am missing something here. You can use select and the relationship between parent with id and child with class

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div id="anything">
  <div>
    <div class="something">
      What I need 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#anything .something').text.strip())
```